# Selenium webdriver/grid on Windows 7 machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

currently I can execute the selenium scripts for Windows XP and Vista using Selenium node:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="E:\selenium-hq\chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="E:\selenium-hq\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.29.0\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 3 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=3,platform=VISTA
```

But how to execute the same scripts for Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Change the Platform parameter as "ANY" instead of "VISTA" and try it.

Comment: I tried. but it is not executing on windows 7 machine. only executing on XP and vista. but I need the enum value to execute it on windows 7 also.

Comment: Is the Grid showing the nodes? If it isn't what is the stacktrace?